# If statement does not work i comparing to variable

Tags: javascript, variables, if-statement

The below if statement in the for loop doe not trigger when the parameter is `value+ac_over_value===valueOfB`, but if for example `valueOfA` = 1, `valueOfB` = 2 and `valueOfC` = 1 and I set the parameter of the if statement to `value+ac_over_value===2` it does work. Why does the statement not work if comparing to a variable?

```
function getN(decP){
var valueOfA = document.getElementById("a-f").value;
var valueOfB = document.getElementById("b-f").value;
var valueOfC = document.getElementById("c-f").value;
var result = Math.pow(10, (decP*-1));
a_c = valueOfA*valueOfC;
var neg_a_c;
var pos_a_c;
if(a_c<0){
    neg_a_c = a_c;
    pos_a_c = a_c*-1
}
else{
    pos_a_c = a_c;
    neg_a_c = a_c*-1;
}
for(value=pos_a_c;value>=neg_a_c;value-=result){
    ac_over_value = a_c/value;
    if(value+ac_over_value === valueOfB){
        divideByCoefficient(value, ac_over_value);
    }
}
};
```

Answer (score 1):

=== means they have to be of the same type. Check to make sure the types are the same. Otherwise just use ==

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to cast valueOfA, valueOfB and valueOfC to the same type as ac_over_value.  Use parseFloat or parseInt depending on what is needed.

Ex.

```
var valueOfB = parseFloat(document.getElementById("b-f").value);
```

Like FirstLegion said === checks type not only value.

Comment: I have tried your amendments, but it still does not work. The code now looks as follows:`for(value=pos_a_c;value>=neg_a_c;value-=result){                   value = parseFloat(value);
 a_c = (a_c);
 ac_over_value = a_c/value;
 ac_over_value = parseFloat(ac_over_value);
 valueOfB = parseFloat(valueOfB);
 if(value+ac_over_value == valueOfB){
  divideByCoefficient(value, ac_over_value);
 }
}`

Comment: I have done some more modifying the code and it now works. Thanks for all your help!